# How to fix YouTube API Rate Limit Error? - Requests Spiked with No Change in Application

Tags: youtube-api

Connecting Domo to the YouTube Analytics API for reporting purposes using the pre-built Domo connector.

Previously (Nov. 2018) was running 10 distinct data sets daily with no issues. In late Dec. A scheduling change was accidentally made that made the data attempt to pull multiple times a day, causing the rate limit to be reached.

This was fixed in January, and the schedule was reverted back to the once daily that worked for all of November and part of Dec.

But now running only a single data set causes us to reach out rate limit and if we try to run any of the others we get the "rate limit exceeded" error.

We've already adjusted the quotas to the highest level available in the developer's console and are not having any luck finding an answer on how to fix.

Comment: To help you start with, you can try to retrofit your usage based on the values of each call stated in the documentation. Try to calculate how much quota does your calls used, visit [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#calculating-quota-usage). If you have calculated and proved that it needed an increase, you can apply for an increase [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/quotas).

Comment: Requesting an increase only allows you to request up to 100K/day, which is already our limit.